# How to convert response string to json object

Tags: java, android, json

I am getting response with okhttp library android java from a url and i converted that response to string.below is response string :

Here is the response string :

`"{\"data\":{\"refrenceCode\":\"upfF+kMKv4Q=\",\"identityTypeId\":\"NV25GlPuOnQ=\",\"idNumber\":\"1000\",\"dateOfBirth\":19961004,\"registrationDate\":\"2020-05-12T12:03:47.647\",\"mobile\":\"0022343 \",\"regionId\":\"NV25GlPuOnQ=\",\"cityId\":\"NV25GlPuOnQ=\",\"carTypeId\":\"NV25GlPuOnQ=\",\"carNumber\":\"aa 000\"},\"status\":true,\"errorCodes\":[]}"`

and when i tried to convert that string to json objectwith below method;

`JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject(responsestring);`

I got following json exception :

`org.json.JSONException: Value {"data":{"refrenceCode":"upfF+kMKv4Q=","identityTypeId":"NV25GlPuOnQ=","idNumber":"1000","dateOfBirth":19961004,"registrationDate":"2020-05-12T12:03:47.647","mobile":"0022343 ","regionId":"NV25GlPuOnQ=","cityId":"NV25GlPuOnQ=","carTypeId":"NV25GlPuOnQ=","carNumber":"aa 000"},"status":true,"errorCodes":[]} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject`

How it can be fixed?

Comment: Why is your "response string" double-quoted? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: i am getting from a url

Comment: I think @chrylis-onstrike- is on the correct path ... try replacing \" with " and removing the first and last "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution based on the collective work in the comments:

```
responsestring = responsestring.substring(1, responsestring.length - 1).replace("\\\"", "\"");
```

Thanks for @chrylis-onstrike- observation, it helped.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it by removing first and last " and then replacing \ like below

responsestring = responsestring.replace("\","");